# What role will DBA have in EF 4.1 Code First Model

Tags: .net, sql, entity-framework

With EF 4.1 Code First Model I find hard to see what role a DBA will play in DB design and creation. How do you see the task of database design being taken up by DotNet Developers.

Comment: Executing schema update scripts? hah!

Answer (score 1):

If we have a company, where

- .net developers will be designing DB's through EF Code First
- With no real knowledged of DB-design/Performance
- and a lot of TPT Inheritance

I think his role will be

1. Expressing Disbelief with management and warning about the
   problems that will arise
2. Troubleshoot performance problems
3. Pull out hair
4. Try to teach developers basic DB-design
5. Troubleshoot performance problems
6. Bang head against wall
7. Redesign complete Databases
8. Troubleshoot performance problems
9. Look on the internet for other job-postings

   ....

Comment: I dunno, your answer insinuates "code first" means you don't do any database design, which is definitely not true. What "code first" really means, in my experience at least, is that you don't have yet another isolated team that will balk at every suggestion that their wonderfully normalized, academically perfect, closed database schema is a poor fit for the work the application actually needs to perform, and they stop dictating how the problem domain needs to change in order to fit their database.

Comment: I'm talking about developers who never learned to design a database don't know anything about designing a database and don't care to learn about it because they believe EF will do this for them and will take responsibility. So I'm not really AGAINST the technology but more against the wrong reason why people will use it

Comment: What I was trying to illustrate through thick, thick sarcasm, is that any integrated team that doesn't work together to produce a well-thought-out design will turn out garbage. What I like about "code first" approach is it allows the two teams to speak a common language without having to be particularly fluent in the others' tongue, while retaining the fidelity of their area or responsibility, see practical results, and refactor/improve in quick iterations. Is it perfect? No. But I simply don't agree that "code first" is a ruinous endeavor.

Comment: I'm bashing BAD/WRONG expectations/use of a technology and not GOOD expectations/use of a technology. there is a specific context which I provide, if you want to ignore that context and still feel attacked, that is up to you

Comment: I don't feel attacked, I'm only offering a dissenting opinion.

Answer (score 0):

DBA is an administrator not a developer. I think you are thinking of SQL Developers and you can still use them for data modelling (even if expressed in C# code), writing Stored Procs when required etc.

Comment: Yes Pratik, I did mean SQL Developer. Thanks for pointing it out.